# google maps with image overlay in cordova / phonegap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, overlay

I'm creating an app in Cordova/Phonegap. I want to add Google Maps with image overlay. I include script with map in MapView.js:

```
$.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp',function(){
   $.getScript('./lib/InitializeMap.js',function(){
   });
});
```

InitializeMap.js code is here: http://pastebin.com/TqjE4CVm

As the result application displays just grey div which should contain map with overlay but there is no image neither map.

In Chrome console i get:
`Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`

I want also to add that normal map without overlay works with following code: http://pastebin.com/vgtgUzSP .

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to use my plugin [phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin)?

You can build your app with Google Maps SDKs on Android and iOS, and control it from JavaScript easily.
[image]